# Web browser applications program language?

Tags: java, web-applications

I would like to write various web browser games and apps to post to my own personal website, mostly for fun. I'm pretty familiar with Java and starting to get into C a little.  As I understand it, I cant just run a common java application from a web browser but have to use the JApplet class or Applet class(or possibly others.) Can I use a JApplet to make fairly sophisticated games or is it really just for basic display images?  I'm willing to learn something completely outside of Java.

I've been browsing the web but am a little overwhelmed in deciding how I should go about this. I would like to make games that are pretty simple graphically, but can remember things like a characters inventory.

Its really just a place to host different games and things I make. How should I go about this?

I hope this isn't too vague.

Comment: JavaScript? There are tons of libraries and game frameworks.

Comment: Forget about applets. Nobody uses them anymore. And Chrome doesn't even support them anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The only language you can guarantee within a web browser is JavaScript. You can write highly sophisticated games using JavaScript, so this shouldn't be a major problem - you can see an example written using [Unreal Engine and JavaScript on YouTube](https://youtu.be/BV32Cs_CMqo).